# How to maintain decimals when dividing with numpy arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, floating-point, division

So, I was working on implementing my own version of the Statsitical Test of Homogeneity in Python where the user would submit a list of lists and the fuction would compute the corresponding chi value.

One issue I found was that my function was removing decimals when performing division, resulting in a somewhat innaccurate chi value for small sample sizes.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats


def test_of_homo(list1):
    a = np.array(list1)
    #n = a.size
    num_rows = a.shape[0]
    num_cols = a.shape[1]
    dof = (num_cols-1)*(num_rows-1)
    column_totals = np.sum(a, axis=0)
    row_totals = np.sum(a, axis=1)
    n = sum(row_totals)
    b = np.array(list1)
    c = 0
    for x in range(num_rows):
      for y in range(num_cols):
        print("X is " + str(x))
        print("Y is " + str(y))
        print("a[x][y] is " + str(a[x][y]))
        print("row_totals[x] is " + str(row_totals[x]))
        print("column_total[y] is " + str(column_totals[y]))
        b[x][y] = (float(row_totals[x])*float(column_totals[y]))/float(n)
        print("b[x][y] is " + str(b[x][y]))
        numerator = ((a[x][y]) - b[x][y])**2
        chi =  float(numerator)/float(b[x][y])
        c = float(c)+ float(chi)
    print(b)
    print(c)
    print(stats.chi2.cdf(c, df=dof))
    print(1-(stats.chi2.cdf(c, df=dof)))

listc = [(21, 36, 30), (48, 26, 19)]

test_of_homo(listc)
```

When the resulted were printed I saw that the `b[x][y]` values were `[[33 29 23] [35 32 25]]` instead of like `33.35, 29.97, 23.68` etc. This caused my resulting chi value to be 15.58 with a p of 0.0004 instead of the expected 14.5.

I tried to convert everything to float but that didn't seem to work. Using the `decimal.Decimal(b[x][y])` resulted in a type error. Any help?

Comment: You don't need the `float` calls.  And use `b[x, y]` indexing.

Comment: In general `numpy` (and python) creates floats as needed.  `1/2` is a float.  But if you assign float values to an array that has a `int` dtype, they will be truncated.  The assignment does not change the `dtype` of the array.  Often when helping debug code I ask - for the arrays in question, what's the `shape` and the `dtype`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem could be due to the numbers you are providing to the function in the list.  Note that if you convert a list to a Numpy array without specifying the data type it will try to guess based on the values:

```
>>> listc = [(21, 36, 30), (48, 26, 19)]
>>> a = np.array(listc)
>>> a.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

Here is how you force conversion to a desired data type:

```
>>> a = np.array(listc, dtype=float)
>>> a.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Try that in the first and 9th lines of your function and see if it solves the problem.  If you do this you shouldn't need to use `float()` all the time.

Comment: Thanks so much. But, I also had to add the "dtype=float" to b as well. Since that is the array that is holding the values before they get subtracted and divided for the test.

Comment: Yes I noticed that.  You could also use `b = a.copy()` instead.